# Splitting strings with spaces

Tags: java, file-read

So I take in a line from a .txt file and turn it into a string. I would like to split the string up by |, but I also have spaces before and after it that is messing with the code, here is what I have so far:

```
File file = new File(fileLocation);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
String line;
String[] words;
while(sc.hasNext()){
    line = sc.next();
    words = line.split("\\|");
    this.german.add(words[0]);
    this.english.add(words[1]);
}
```

An example line would be something like: in blue|in blau

I would also like to keep the spaces.

The .txt file would be:

in Rot|in red

in Blau|in blue

in Grun|in green

in Gelb|in Yellow

It would add all the items on the left of the | to the german list, and all of the ones on the right to the english list.

Ah, figured it out, the sc.next() is the next String, not the next line, I replaced it with sc.nextLine() and everything worked, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some input data and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call

```
line.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

beforehand; this will get rid of **all** the spaces. If you only want leading and trailing spaces from the split strings removed, use

```
words[i].trim()
```

instead.

Comment: What if I want to keep the spaces?

Comment: If you want no spaces removed, your method is fine. For leading/trailing spaces, see my answer (I updated it).

Answer (score 2):

Use the following pattern:

`words = line.split("\\s+\\|\\s+");`

Comment: If I read this correctly, this requires that the line has at least one whitespace character before and after the |.